# Scala: Recursion with future Stack overflow error

Tags: scala, recursion, stack-overflow, concurrent.futures

Consider below code snippet. Too many take() calls will result in stack overflow error. What is the good strategy to overcome such scenarios?

```
def take(): Future[Int] = {
    val processResponseF: Future[Boolean] = performSomeAction()
    processResponseF.flatMap(
      processResponse => {
        if(processResponse)
          Future.successful(100)
        else
          take()
      }
    )
  }

def performSomeAction(): Future[Boolean] = {
  //This returns future of boolean
}
```

Assumption - 
1. Method signature should not be changed

Comment: Use scalaz or monix Task as they address the very problem you described.

Comment: your code will not compile as is.

Comment: Your code example works on my machine with scala.concurrent.ExecutionContext.Implicits.global, (i.e. stack is fine)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Too many take() calls will result in stack overflow error.

It won't. When a method that returns a `Future` recursively calls itself, all that method knows is that it has a future value that will be filled (maybe) later. The actual code is executed on a different stack, as it needs to be done asynchronously from the original call, and may not even happen on the same thread.

Comment: But how about I change line in else-
def take(): Future[Int] = {
    val processResponseF: Future[Boolean] = performSomeAction()
    processResponseF.flatMap(
      processResponse => {
        if(processResponse)
          Future.successful(100)
        else
          Future.successful(10) + take() //changed line
      }
    )
  }

Now will it need to keep stack of old calls?

Comment: @user3635344 Then it doesn't compile, because you cannot write `Future(10) + take()`. You can't add futures without mapping.

Comment: Hmm. Right. It will be needed to write in future block. Thank you very much. :)